# Stream MP3 files with Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, stream, blob, mp3, storage

Is it possible to stream MP3 or WAV files with Microsoft Azure?

I want to have file which can be played with any js-player including to start the playback from any point the users wants (like the soundcloud player,...).
I tried to use the Blob Storage for that, but thats not possible because it does support streaming so the file has to be downloaded completely to jump to a certain point of the song.

Is there a way to make this possible with the Blob Storage? Or do I have to user Azure Media Services (tried that but only found support for video)?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the service version of the storage. I had to set it manually via a Java program to a higher version (2014-02-14).

Here is the code. You need the azure SDK (https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java) and the slf4j, lang3 and fasterxml libs.

```
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.CloudStorageAccount;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlobClient;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.ServiceProperties;

public class storage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount;
        ServiceProperties serviceProperties;

        try {
            storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse("AccountName=<storageName>;AccountKey=<storageAccessKey>;DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http");    


            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();

            // Get the current service properties
            serviceProperties = blobClient.downloadServiceProperties(); 


            // Set the default service version to 2011-08-18 (or a higher version like 2012-03-01)
            serviceProperties.setDefaultServiceVersion("2014-02-14");

            // Save the updated service properties
            blobClient.uploadServiceProperties(serviceProperties);  
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.print("Exception");
        }

    };
};
```